# SSL on SharePoint

Tags: document, file, ssl, office

I am facing some problems on SharePoint.
I've got a SharePoint site (let's say HTTP : //intranet.domain.be)
We wanted to use this intranet from outside.
So we decided to set an Extranet (HTTPS : //intranet.domain.be)
To do so, we installed a SSL certificate. Everything is going well but one thing.
on HTTP, i can check out, open, edit a document like a word document.
on HTTPS, i try to open the same file but when i do so, a pop up appears and ask to select a certificate.
None of them doesn't allow me to open the file :s
Does Anyone have any idea what's going on?
I checked the SSL implementation, the SP config, but everything seems to be ok...
Let me know if you have an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Your IIS SSL configuration is not right, you are mixing client certificates with SSL server certificates. You want to use SSL Server certificates for the site, not client certificates. Disable client certificates, and configure correct SSL certificate in IIS web site bindings.

Review the article for details [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907274).